# Google Custom Search Does not show correct results

Tags: ajax, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api, jsonresult

I'm creating an app in javascript in which I need some total number of google results. I tried using Google custom search api but it does not show all the results and the number of results are less than the number of results on google search.

Many people are facing this problem, I have tried some solutions but didn't work for me. I wonder how some sites are able to get exact results for a keyword on google.

Answer (score 0):

me too.
The result is 0 when searchType = image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjRLX.png)